# undefine index:no in c:/wamp/www/Hotel 18\confirm_booking.php on line 3

Tags: php

error : undefine index:no in c:/wamp/www/Hotel 18\confirm_booking.php on line 3.

```
    $roomno=$_GET['no'];
    include('connection.php');
    if(isset($_Request['btnconfirm']))
    {

    $cust=$_POST['custname'];
    $room=$_POST['custroom'];
    $ar=$_POST['arrv'];
    $dep=$_POST['depr'];
    $total=$_POST['total'];
    echo mysql_query("inserted into checkout(customer_name,room_no,arrival_time,departure_time,total,status) values('$cust','$room','$ar','$dep','$total','PAID')");
    mysql_query("update room_booking set status='Clear' where name='$cust' and roomNo='$room'");
 }
 ?>
```

note: i have taken 'no' as a reference from a page, and it is working quit well, but on submitting the form, still an error occurred related to the `$_GET['no']`         what mistake i did ?**

Comment: why are you using $_GET and $_POST at the same time ? and you are not checking if isset **no** or not

Comment: You can have a URL query under any method. It may not be his style to properly check for values. Stay on topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

```
if(isset($_Request['btnconfirm']))
```

`$_Request` is a [`superglobal`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php) which must be in uppercase `$_REQUEST`

change it to:

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['btnconfirm']))
```

I suggest that you switch to using `mysqli_*` with prepared statements or PDO. `mysql_*` functions are deprecated and will be deleted from future PHP releases.

As it stands now, you are open to SQL injection.

- [**Read this article**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/) on how to prevent SQL injection.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously "no" isn't being passed within the query string, at least some of the time.